# Time series forecasting using SVM

Tags: time-series, svm, forecasting, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to set up a Python code for forecasting a time series, using SVM libraries of scikit-learn.

My data contains $X$ values at a day interval for the last one years, and I need to predict $y$ for a month of the next year. Here's what I have set up -

```
SVR().fit(X, y).predict(X)
```

But for this prediction to work, I need the $X$ value for the next month, which is not available. How do I set this up to predict future $y$ values?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the problem here. Is it that your data have a feature and response variables X and Y respectively? If this is so then you will have control over the feature and you can predict y values according to it. So, if for example I am looking at the effect of sales Y(t) as a function of time with respect to the change in money spent on advertisement X(t) again with respect to time, and you got a model for the data then the prediction from that model will need the past data, the values of X(t) for the next month to make predictions.

Comment: You may try to find a relationship between $y$ and *lagged* $X$, and exploit it to forecast $y$ using the $X$ values that *are* available. Otherwise you may forecast $X$ and then use it to obtain the forecasts of $y$.

Comment: What are X and y in reality -- is y e.g. yes/no or red/yellow/green ? (([SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) is for discrete y.)